# Magento: how to load product along its all data as it is used in admin

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to get bundle options data.   using this : `$product->getBundleOptionsData`   I need to use this, as I'm trying to change data programmatically and I would like to do it in a way that's as close as used in admin .

However, when I var_dump the result of the above function I get `NULL`  while in admin side in bundle model product type I get correctly the data.

When I var_dump `$product` in my own file I get much shorter data than when I var_dump in bundle model product type save function.

what do I need to do to load all data of the product, so I can use `getBundleOptionsData`.  I looked in several files and googled, but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I made it work to get bundle options data so I can manipulate it.    I found the main code in magento's model bundle observer class duplicateProduct function:  I needed however to add option_id (careful not to forget that)

here is the code in it's final stage.

```
$product->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);
$optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($product);
$selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
    $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
    $product
);
$optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);

$optionRawData = array();
$selectionRawData = array();

$i = 0;
foreach ($optionCollection as $option) {
    $optionRawData[$i] = array(
            'option_id' => $option->getOptionId(), //my addition. important otherwise, options going to be duplicated
            'required' => $option->getData('required'),
            'position' => $option->getData('position'),
            'type' => $option->getData('type'),
            'title' => $option->getData('title')?$option->getData('title'):$option->getData('default_title'),
            'delete' => ''
        );
    foreach ($option->getSelections() as $selection) {
        $selectionRawData[$i][] = array(
            'product_id' => $selection->getProductId(),
            'position' => $selection->getPosition(),
            'is_default' => $selection->getIsDefault(),
            'selection_price_type' => $selection->getSelectionPriceType(),
            'selection_price_value' => $selection->getSelectionPriceValue(),
            'selection_qty' => $selection->getSelectionQty(),
            'selection_can_change_qty' => $selection->getSelectionCanChangeQty(),
            'delete' => ''
        );
    }
    $i++;
}

$product->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);   //changed it to $product
$product->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);  //changed it to $product
```

you can either now change on the raw data in optionsrawdata. or getBundleOptionsData. and same for the other one.

Comment: can u answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055966/magento-how-to-update-bundle-product-programmatically

Comment: It is not working for some products for me. I have debuged that and found the issue (ie `$optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection)` is failing )

Comment: In what way is it failing? is selectionCollection empty? is product loaded? is it bundle?