# Change sort order for bundle product item selected magento

Tags: magento, collections, magento-1.7, bundle

I want to sort magento bundle product selected sort order on magento admin.i have changed below code file but nothing happen.i don't know from where it collect collection of product so i can set order by name. I have set order by name on this function but nothing changed.

**Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option**

```
public function getOptions()
{
    if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->setStoreFilter($this->getProduct()->getStoreId(),
            $this->getProduct());

        $optionCollection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($this->getProduct());

        $selectionCollection = $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
            $this->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($this->getProduct()),
            $this->getProduct()
        );

        $this->_options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection);
        if ($this->getCanReadPrice() === false) {
            foreach ($this->_options as $option) {
                if ($option->getSelections()) {
                    foreach ($option->getSelections() as $selection) {
                        $selection->setCanReadPrice($this->getCanReadPrice());
                        $selection->setCanEditPrice($this->getCanEditPrice());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->_options;
}
```

[image]

**Please Help**

Comment: post to magento.stackexchange.com to get answers.. Magento has it's own site now

Comment: Alternatively, you can put some ranking in the `Position` column to achieve this.

Comment: i know the position is the way but we have to give order manually so it is not good way.i want it order by name when setting collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class to modify/extend is `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type`, then function `getSelectionsCollection`.

```
public function getSelectionsCollection($optionIds, $product = null)
{
    $keyOptionIds = (is_array($optionIds) ? implode('_', $optionIds) : '');
    $key = $this->_keySelectionsCollection . $keyOptionIds;
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($key)) {
        $storeId = $this->getProduct($product)->getStoreId();
        $selectionsCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('bundle/selection_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
                ->addAttributeToSelect('tax_class_id') //used for calculation item taxes in Bundle with Dynamic Price
                ->setFlag('require_stock_items', true)
                ->setFlag('product_children', true)
                //->setPositionOrder() //comment this line
                ->setOrder('name', 'asc') //add this line
                ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
                ->setStoreId($storeId)
                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                ->setOptionIdsFilter($optionIds);

        if (!Mage::helper('catalog')->isPriceGlobal() && $storeId) {
            $websiteId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
            $selectionsCollection->joinPrices($websiteId);
        }

        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($key, $selectionsCollection);
    }
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($key);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro you are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? [Magento: how to load product along its all data as it is used in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763296/magento-how-to-load-product-along-its-all-data-as-it-is-used-in-admin)

You can modify `$selectionRawData` by calling some PHP function and sorting it alphabetically.